# Firebase data updates, but RecyclerView won't refresh. How to fix?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Android RecyclerView not updating with Firebase data in Kotlin. onDataChange is called, but RecyclerView is not reflecting the changes. Here are my code snippets and log outputs. How can I fix this issue?

I'm trying to display data from Firebase database in a RecyclerView in my Android app. The onDataChange function is being called, and it seems like the data is being retrieved correctly, but the RecyclerView is not updating. I'm having an issue with reflecting the data into the RecyclerView. Below, you can find relevant code snippets and log outputs:

Creating RecyclerView and Adapter
Retrieving data using ValueEventListener
onDataChange and setCategories functions
The log outputs are as follows:

```
class CategoryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)

        // categoryAdapter'ı başlat
        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(emptyList())

        // RecyclerView'in özelliklerini ayarla
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCategories)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = categoryAdapter
        Log.d("CategoryFragment", "onCreateView is called")
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("CategoryFragment", "onViewCreated is called")

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://foxycodecasestudy-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference("categories")

        Log.d("CategoryFragment", "Database reference: $databaseReference")

        // Debug log
        Log.d("CategoryFragment", "onViewCreated is called")

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val categories = mutableListOf<CategoryModel>()

                // Debug log
                Log.d("CategoryFragment", "onDataChange is called")

                for (categorySnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val enName = categorySnapshot.child("en").getValue(String::class.java)
                    val trName = categorySnapshot.child("tr").getValue(String::class.java)

                    Log.d("CategoryFragment", "enName: $enName, trName: $trName")

                    if (enName != null && trName != null) {
                        val category = CategoryModel(enName, trName)
                        categories.add(category)
                    }
                }

                categoryAdapter.setCategories(categories)
                categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Log.d("CategoryFragment", "RecyclerView updated. Item count: ${categoryAdapter.itemCount}")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                val errorMessage = databaseError.message
                Log.e("CategoryFragment", "FirebaseError: $errorMessage")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```
class CategoryAdapter(private var categories: List<CategoryModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    fun setCategories(categories: List<CategoryModel>) {
        this.categories = categories
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d("CategoryAdapter", "Categories updated. Count: ${categories.size}")
        Log.d("CategoryAdapter", "First category: ${categories.firstOrNull()?.en}")
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val category = categories[position]
        holder.bind(category)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categories.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val textViewTrName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryEn)
        private val textViewEnName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryTr)

        fun bind(category: CategoryModel) {
            textViewTrName.text = category.tr
            textViewEnName.text = category.en
        }
    }

}
```

[Log 1]

> onCreateView is called
> ...

[Log 2]

> onDataChange is called
> enName: Family, trName: Aile
> enName: Nature, trName: Doğa
> ...

[Log 3]

> Categories updated. Count: 10
> First category: Family
> RecyclerView updated. Item count: 10

Comment: try to add new items into list instead of setting new value to categories variable

Comment: Despite trying to follow your suggestion of adding new items to the 'categories' variable instead of setting a completely new value, the RecyclerView is still not updating as expected. Do you have any other recommendations or anything specific I should look into?

Comment: If you try to log the value of `category` inside `onBindViewHolder`, are you getting something printed out? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: I don't know how it happened, but the data started coming suddenly. Thanks :)